# Openerp get value of field on view

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

Hello I want to retrieve the value of a field on the view. For example on the `mrp.bom` view when I edit the Reference I want to be able to get this new value. Whenever I try to use `self.browse` I get the value in the database.

```py
mrp_bom = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
ref = mrp_bom.code
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question well, but just in case, have you tried the decorator `@api.onchange`? (only if you are working with v8 or later).

If you create a new method with the decorator `@api.onchange('ref')` above it, this method will be executed each time the value of `ref` field changes, and you will be able to get this one.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, Yes actually I'm applying an onchange on a Many2Many ('bom_line_ids') but for the simplicity of my question I used reference as an example. Whenever I try to apply the @api.onchange on this M2M it returns not the result I want, the onchange is only triggered on delete

Comment: Ok @Jesse, I understand. So if the field is a many2many, you have to take into account that if you put only the many2many field in the decorator, the method will be triggered only when you create or remove records in that many2many field. If the method depends on a specific field of the many2many, you have to write `@api.onchange('your_m2m', 'your_m2m.the_field')`. This way the method will be triggered each time the field of the many2many changes, the record is deleted or a new record is created.

Comment: Thanks I'll definitly give it a try.